# Replace a specific string character index into 0

Tags: java, actionlistener, actionevent

I have built a table chart application. I have a calculate button with an action event. So, first of all, the action event will getText from a textfield button named field. After that it will convert the string into int. But, I want to check one thing before converting the string into int. That is, I would like to check if the string character index [0] is equal to '-', if so then it will be changed to 0. I have tried to put an if condition like

```
if(text.charAt[0] == "-"){text.setCharAt(0, "0")}
```

but it is saying condition is not comparable from char to string.
Is there any other way to replace an index character into 0?

Here's the action listener code:

```
calculate = JButton; result = JTextArea; field = JTextField;
calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    result.setText(null);
    String text = field.getText();
    Integer i = Integer.valueOf(text);
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++){
    result.append((i + " " + "x" + " " + j + "=" + " " +(i * j)) + "\n");
}});
```

I have tried the code below but i can't figure out how to assign 'text' to 'str':

```
    if(text.charAt(0) == '-'){
     StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(text);
     str.setCharAt(0, '0');
}
```

Moreover; when the new string is set to 'str' instead of 'text', I could not assign str as a string, such as `StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(str);` Therefore; I am basically stuck in this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In :

```
text.charAt[0] == "-"
```

- `text.charAt[0]` is a **char**.
- `"-"` is a **String**.

Moreover, you should never use `==` on a Character or a String. Use `equals()` instead.

Try

```
text.charAt[0].equals('-');
```

Comment: both of the codes are working fine but after that when I am putting `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(str);` instead of "text", it is not accepting because of str is a string builder.@Arnaud Denoyelle

Comment: @user1946440 Use `StringBuilder#toString()` : `Integer.valueOf(str.toString());`

Comment: @user1946440 convert String Builder to String by using `toString()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Arnaud Denoyelle, the `Integer.valueOf(str.toString());` worked.

Answer (score 0):

try 
    `if(text.charAt[0] == '-'){text.setCharAt(0, '0')}`

"a" - String

'a' - char

Answer (score 0):

```
text.charAt[0] == "-"
```

In this line checking a string `"-"`  change it as `'-'`

Instead of `==` , use `equals()` as follows:

```
text.charAt[0].equals('-')
```